# Python multithreading - memory not released when ran using While statement

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, jupyter-notebook

I built a scraper (worker) launched XX times through multithreading (via Jupyter Notebook, python 2.7, anaconda).
Script is of the following format, as described on python.org:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

When I run the script as is, there are no issues.  Memory is released after script finishes.

However, I want to run the said script 20 times (batching of sort),
so I turn the script mentioned into a function, and run the function using code below:

```
def multithreaded_script():
   my script #code from above

x = 0
while x<20:
  x +=1
  multithredaded_script()
```

memory builds up with each iteration, and eventually the system start writing it to disk.

Is there a way to clear out the memory after each run?

I tried:

1. setting all the variables to None
2. setting `sleep(30)` at end of each iteration (in case it takes time for ram to release)

and nothing seems to help.
Any ideas on what else I can try to get the memory to clear out after each run within the While statement?
If not, is there a better way to execute my script XX times, that would not eat up the ram?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also tried to importing garbage collect module ( import gc
gc.enable()   ), and manually adding gc.collect() after each worker function runs...  no dice.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (using mem profiler).
The line by line analysis in this package look nice, however, I am not able to install it for some reason.  any idea if there are other packages that provide line by line mem analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Solution: Make sure to end each function with return to ensure all local variables are destroyed from ram**

Per Pavel's suggestion, I used memory tracker (unfortunately suggested mem tracker did't work for me, so i used [Pympler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler).)

Implementation was fairly simple:

```
from pympler.tracker import SummaryTracker
tracker = SummaryTracker()

~~~~~~~~~YOUR CODE

tracker.print_diff()
```

The tracker gave a nice output, which made it obvious that local variables generated by functions were not being destroyed.

Adding "**return**" at the end of every function fixed the issue.

**Takeaway:**
If you are writing a function that processes info/generates local variables, but doesn't pass local variables to anything else -> make sure to end the function with **return** anyways.  This will prevent any issues that you may run into with memory leaks.

**Additional notes on memory usage & BeautifulSoup:**
If you are using BeautifulSoup / BS4 with multithreading and multiple workers, and have limited amount of free ram, you can also use `soup.decompose()` to destroy soup variable right after you are done with it, instead of waiting for the function to return/code to stop running.